# Sending http request using RestTemplate(spring-social) via proxy

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-social

I need to send request to twitter using spring-social. Application runs from war in tomcat.
When request should be redirected by `ConnectionControler.class`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{providerId}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView connect(@PathVariable String providerId, NativeWebRequest request) {
    ConnectionFactory<?> connectionFactory = connectionFactoryLocator.getConnectionFactory(providerId);
    MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(); 
    preConnect(connectionFactory, parameters, request);
    try {
        return new RedirectView(connectSupport.buildOAuthUrl(connectionFactory, request, parameters));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sessionStrategy.setAttribute(request, PROVIDER_ERROR_ATTRIBUTE, e);
        return connectionStatusRedirect(providerId, request);
    }
}
```

I get `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

The same problem was in another application which based on spring-boot, problem was solved by adding VM arguments

```
-Dhttp.proxyPort=9050 
-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.10.10
-Dhttps.proxyPort=9050 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.10.10
```

But for application running from war in tomcat it doesn't work. Also i tried to set arguments programmatically, that is generally the same, when spring starting initialize context:

```
 System.setProperty( "http.proxyPort", "9050" );
 System.setProperty( "https.proxyPort", "9050" );
 System.setProperty( "http.proxyHost", "192.168.10.10" );
 System.setProperty( "https.proxyHost", "192.168.10.10" );
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue